# Conditioning on $Y=y$ when $\mathbb{P}\{Y=y\} = 0$

Tags: probability

#### Setup

For continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, the conditional probability can be written as

$$
\mathbb{P}\{X \in dx \mid Y = y\} = \frac{\mathbb{P}\{X \in dx, Y \in dy\}}{\mathbb{P}\{Y \in dy\}}
$$

where the notation $\mathbb{P}\{X \in dx\}$ means that $X$ is in some infinitesimally small range of values:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)] = \int \varphi(x) \mathbb{P}\{X \in dx\} = \lim_{|x_{i+1} - x_i| \rightarrow 0} \sum_i \varphi(x_i) \mathbb{P}\{x_i < X \leq x_{i+1}\}
$$

This kind of calculus is needed because the probability of a specific outcome when there are an infinite number of outcomes is $0$. Or $\mathbb{P}\{X=x\} = 0$.

---

#### Questions

I have two questions about this notation:

1. Why is it fine to condition on an event that has probability 0? Philosophically, it's as if probability theory tells us the event can never happen but we can condition on the event having happened.
2. I do not understand why it is okay to condition on $Y = y$ but say that the conditional probability is equal to $Y$ being in some infinitesimal range. Is it okay because the infinitesimals cancel out?

Comment: Don't worry, many people have asked this question before. This opens the gates to the idea of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation .

Answer (score 1):

I was a little confused by the notation used in my class, so I read the equivalent section in Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis. I prefer their explanation and document it here. They note that for a small interval $[x, x+\delta]$, we have

$$
\mathbb{P}([x, x+\delta]) = \int_x^{x+\delta} f_X (t) dt \approx f_X (x) \cdot \delta
$$

Where the approximately equal sign just means that we approximate the area under this smooth, continuous curve with very small rectangles as in calculus. Now the conditional distribution can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(x < X \leq x+\delta_1 \mid y < Y \leq y+\delta_2)
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(x < X \leq x+\delta_1, y < Y \leq y+\delta_2)}{\mathbb{P}(y < Y \leq y+\delta_2)}
\\
&\approx \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y) \delta_1 \delta_2}{f_Y(y) \delta_2}
\\
&= f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) \delta_1
\end{align}
$$

In words, $f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) \delta_1$ is probability that $X$ is within a small interval $[x, x+\delta_1]$, given that $Y$ is within a small interval $[y, y+\delta_2]$. Now note that $f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) \delta_1$ does not depend on $\delta_2$. It does not matter how big or small this interval is. So we can think about the limiting case where $\delta_2$ decreases to $0$ and we write

$$
\mathbb{P}(x < X \leq x+\delta_1 \mid Y = y) \approx f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) \delta_1
$$

Philosophically, I was confused because I wasn't sure what it meant to condition on an event that happened with probability $0$. But mathematically this is okay to do because the point is that the answer does not change even if we computed the same quantity for a large $\delta_2$. I believe this is what my professor meant when he said that the "infinitesimals of $Y$ cancel out". No matter what values they take, the calculation is the same and therefore it is okay to take the limiting case.